# Transferring Jekyll to custom domain

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to deploy my Github pages Jekyll site to my own domain. I have not successfully been able to do this with Glynn.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. What are you exactly doing ? From where to where ? Expected result ? Effective result ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have your own domain point to Github pages? You don't have to move anything, just associate your domain name with the Github Pages site;

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/